# cloud not functioning when you set a timeframe for indicator on other timeframes (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have made this indicator on trading view that fills the distance between to moving averages (and it's called a cloud) the cloud works when I don't set a specific timeframe for indicator to get the data from but for example when I put the indicators timeframe on weekly and view it on daily chart everything is right except for the cloud and it doesn't get filled in other timeframes than what you have set the whole indicator on ( in this example it only works on weekly chart and on other time frames it doesn't work) do you know what I should do to make it work?
[image]
[image]

```
StudyName        = "MA Cloud"
ShortStudyName   = "MA cloud" 
study(StudyName, shorttitle=ShortStudyName, overlay=true, resolution="")

source = input(close, title="Source")
typeofMA1 = input(title="Type of Moving Average", defval="EMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "TMA", "HullMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "VWAP"])
length_ma1 = input(30, title = "[ALL but VWAP] Length of Moving Average 1", type=input.integer)
typeofMA2 = input(title="Type of Moving Average", defval="EMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "VWMA", "SMMA", "TMA", "HullMA", "DEMA", "TEMA", "VWAP"])
length_ma2 = input(74, title = "[ALL but VWAP] Length of Moving Average 2", type=input.integer)

color_candles = input(true, title="Color based on trend?")

f_smma(src, len) =>
    smma = 0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

f_hullma(src, length) =>
    wma(2 * wma(src, length / 2) - wma(src, length), round(sqrt(length)))

f_tma(src, length) =>
    sma(sma(src, length), length)

f_dema(src, length) =>
    emaValue = ema(src, length)
    2 * emaValue - ema(emaValue, length)

f_tema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ema(ema1, length)
    ema3 = ema(ema2, length)
    (3 * ema1) - (3 * ema2) + ema3 

f_ma(smoothing, src, length) =>

    iff(smoothing == "RMA",    rma(src, length), 
     iff(smoothing == "SMA",    sma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "EMA",    ema(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "WMA",    wma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "VWMA",   vwma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "SMMA",   f_smma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "HullMA", f_hullma(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "VWAP",   vwap(hlc3),
     iff(smoothing == "DEMA",   f_dema(src, length),
     iff(smoothing == "TEMA",   f_tema(src, length), src))))))))))

MA1 = f_ma(typeofMA1, source, length_ma1)
MA2 = f_ma(typeofMA2, source, length_ma2)

plot_ma1 = plot(MA1, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=3, title = "MA1")
plot_ma2 = plot(MA2, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=3, title = "MA2")

fill_color = MA1 > MA2 ? color.new(color.green, 60) : color.new(color.red, 60)
fill(plot_ma1, plot_ma2, color=fill_color)

// Candles coloring
clr = not color_candles ? na : 
 MA1 > MA2 ? color.new(color.lime, 40) : color.new(color.fuchsia, 40)

barcolor(clr,title="Trend State Bar Colouring")

cond_buy  = MA1 > MA2 and crossover(MA1, MA2)
cond_sell = MA1 < MA2 and crossunder(MA1, MA2)

// green triangle
plotshape(cond_buy, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.large)
// red triangle
plotshape(cond_sell, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.large)


alertcondition(cond_buy,  title='Buy Alert', message="Buy Alert")
alertcondition(cond_sell,  title='Sell Alert', message="Sell Alert")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior if you calculate your script in scope of other timeframe. If you on a `60 min` chart, and setting your indicator time frame to `1D`, then you will be given just 1 value per session of your `60 min` chart.

This is the same as using `security()` function. Info about this can be found here:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#gaps

"Hidden" `gaps` parameter (as you using `security` function implicitly by using `resolution` parameter) can be set in `study()` function as `resolution_gaps = false`:

So you need to rewrite your study call as:

```
study(StudyName, shorttitle=ShortStudyName, overlay=true, resolution="", resolution_gaps = false)
```

Comment: thanks it works now on different timeframes but it has gaps and when I turn off the gaps it stops working is there any way to make it work without gaps?

Comment: Pls show it on the screenshot what gaps you are referring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70410185/moving-average-cloud-not-working-pinescript
I shared screenshots here

Comment: I updated my question and shared screenshots there!!

Comment: Replace 
`fill(plot_ma1, plot_ma2, color=fill_color)` with

`fill(plot_ma1, plot_ma2, color = color.green,  fillgaps = true)`. 

Seems that there is bug that if you use series color returned from expression (`fill_color`) in the `fill()` function with the higher resolution (even with  `fillgaps = true` setting on) it will not show the fill between plots. So for now you may use constant color.